# HTML5: Why are the header/footer tags flow content objects rather than sectioning elements?

Tags: html, html-heading

It would stand to reason if HTML5 was meant to be stricter in document object syntax then header and footer would defined as sectioning elements but are instead explicitly stated as not and are instead categorized as flow content object.

Is there a specific reason to this or just a quirk of the language?
What is considered standard practice?

Comment: This is more of a debate question and not a very good fit for stackoverflow.

Comment: It's a question related directly to standard practice of coding amongst web developers. It most certainly is relevant to stackoverflow as it questions the usage of the tag in a document object outline and what is considered standard/best practice of the tag. Some questions are forced to be opinionated in nature. The same way XHTML, Web Applications 1.0 and HTML4 were all opinions of best usage that were adopted by W3C. All code usage is debatable unless its a syntax rule or mathematical expression.

Answer (score 4):

Headers and footers are elements of a section (contained within). The header introduces the section while the footer is the close to it.

[The header element](https://developers.whatwg.org/sections.html#the-header-element)

> A header element is intended to usually contain the section's heading

[The footer element](https://developers.whatwg.org/sections.html#the-footer-element)

> The footer element represents a footer for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element.

Comment: I understand this part but for that it would not even be needed as the intent for it is to not section off or add mark-up to my document object outline. If I intended to title my sections, even for content which won't contain text, I'd be better using a hidden header object and titling the section appropriately. Are the tags used more for cross-user parsing ease of read or simply a quirk of the language not really needed?

Comment: @James Johnson: Why does an element have to affect the document outline in order to be semantically useful?

Comment: @boltClock That is my question indeed. Is it standard practice to use amongst web developers or simply a personal option? It seems to be the latter as w3c doesn't include it strictly in sectioning content. If its not used by machines to accurately outline the document then I'd rather forego its usage unless its standard usage for allowing other coders to easily parse your code.

Comment: @James Johnson: A semantic element can be useful not only to humans reading your markup, but also to certain clients consuming the markup depending on your application as they may treat certain elements specially (just like how browsers assign styles or behaviors to certain elements). But practically speaking, most authors use header and footer simply because they were advised to and they have nothing to lose (assuming they do so correctly), in which case it might all boil down to personal choice: you can make your document as semantically rich, or not, as you want - regardless of the outline.

Comment: @boltClock That makes perfect sense, and you're right in client usage which I hadn't fully thought out(similar to phrasing content tags). I guess it won't hurt to use for my standards but it just seemed confusing in that I have an aside tag which is a section element but the header and footer weren't.

Comment: @JamesJohnson An aside is a standalone element which is why it is sectioning content.

Comment: @Rob Correct, your answer was semantically right it was just the illustration of its message didn't initially allow me to understand that footer and headers are not semantically meant to mean top-level objects such as they are generally termed and thought of in the deign medium of webwork.

Answer (score 0):

After researching w3c and MDN along with reviewing some outside spec content the `<header>` and `<footer>` seems to have been misunderstood.

While I thought, and I'm sure others have also, that header and footer referred to top level document outlines they can actually go anywhere that are relevant to a **section's** header, **not the document's**.

Example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<nav><!--Sectioning element for navigation-->

<header>
<h1>Navigate simply around the site...</h1>
<p>and learn more</p>
</header><!--All flow content are considered a part of my header inside the nav section -->

<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
</ul>
</nav>
<article>
<section>
<header>
<h1>Main Article Title</h1>
<cite>A sub message</cite><!--Again all content is considered an header of the section-->
</header>
<p>Some content</p> 
</section>
</article>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should make this a comment or edit to your original question and not post this as an answer.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @arcyqwerty This was a complete answer to the question along with Rob's, which wasn't fleshed out fully rather pointing to doc spec. If it was placed in the comment section the code couldn't illustrate the answer fully and usage in a real-world application.

If Rob is worried about points I'll mark/upvote his answer correct but it really didn't answer much as to standard practice, which was asked, and usage in code fully. It simply was a rehash of my original question which referred to W3C spec.

Comment: Update: This question should be getting removed by moderation soon as I flagged it as I never intended to deal with volatility nor ambiguous answering of a question. Do to all parties involved, including mine this question would only confuse an outside user.